# Pause FLV Video after X seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, stream, flv

I'm streaming a flv video and i need to pause the stream on the 15th second. Than after user interaction ( after hiting a button ) to resume the stream.

```
var connection:NetConnection;
var stream:NetStream;
var video:Video;

connection = new NetConnection();

connection.connect(null);

stream = new NetStream(connection);

stream.client = this;

video.attachNetStream(stream);

stream.bufferTime = 1;

stream.receiveAudio(true);

stream.receiveVideo(true);

stream.play("Cashwave.flv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a timer and stop playback when you need to.
Something like this:

```
 //EDIT: import timer class like this
 import flash.utils.Timer;

 var timer:Timer = new Timer(15000,1);
 timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, pauseMyVideo);
 timer.start();

 function pauseMyVideo(e:TimerEvent.TIMER) {
  stream.pause();
  // do other stuff like add resume button
 }
```

Comment: It gives me this: 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: TIMER.

Comment: try to import the Timer class.
import flash.utils.Timer;